# c# gridview with lightbox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

so im trying to implement a lightbox on a gridview. the lightbox i'm using is the one from  [here at particle tree](http://particletree.com/features/lightbox-gone-wild/)

anyway, so basically you need to include a css and rel on your link to make it work. i was able to succesfully include a css class without problems on every cell with TemplateField:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Set of Links">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hyplink" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Link") %>' CssClass="lbAction" NavigateUrl="tolink.aspx?ruleset={0}"></asp:HyperLink>

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="link" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Link") %>'>LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

so that's what i have. mind you, i was just trying it out which one is better, hyperlink or linkbutton so either object i can use as long as i can add a rel attribute on it. 
this is my code behind.

```
void theGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "lbAction";
        e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("rel", "insert");
    }
}
```

i tried this as well

```
protected void theGrid_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.CssClass = "lbAction";

    }
}
```

but i couldn't include a rel on the second one cuz of vs2010 would give me that red squiggle line.

so, thoughts are much appreciated on how to include a rel on a cell.

thanks much!!!

Comment: Are you trying to add the rel attribute to the row or to each of the controls (HyperLink & LinkButton) in a cell?

Comment: each of the controls. basically each cell on the hyperlink column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the attribute to each control, when databininding, you can find each control and add the rel attribute directly.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      HyperLink hpl = (HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("hyplink");
      hpl.Attributes.Add("rel", "insert");
      LinkButton lkb = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("link");
      lkb.Attributes.Add("rel", "insert");
   }
}
```

Comment: Works on my end.  When you run the above code, set breakpoints after the attribute is added to each control and check to see if the newly added attribute is there.

Comment: i see what was wrong, i forgot to add the onrowdatabound on my gridview. worked great! thanks!!